# Apache rewrite rule can't output "?" as argument

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I added an Apache rewrite rule to convert a static static URL to a PHP URL, but I will miss the output after the question mark.

For example:

RewriteRule test/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) 48/thread.php?tid=123 [L]

But it seems every time when I input
http://www.exmple.com/new_sr/test/hi/1d62c59da779043b2f6bda467fdae41a/

I just get the URL

/new_sr/48/thread.php

But I expect to get the URL

48/thread.php?tid=123

"?tid=123" is discarded.

Why?

Comment: Try googling "query string," you need to treat it separately / specially.

Comment: how to treat it spearately? do i need addtional rule or flag?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
RewriteRule test/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*) 48/thread.php?tid=123 [L]
```

BTW, you can test your rules in this link: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/